# Using "hardhat deploy" plugin, and it is not getting the deployed contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

I'm using the hardhat-deploy plugin to deploy the contracts, the plugin successfully deployed the two contracts but, not performing the same this time, what I've done is...

```
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types"
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { VOTING_DELAY, QUORUM_PERCENTAGE, VOTING_PERIOD } from "../helperHardhatConfig";


const deployGovernorContract: DeployFunction = async function(hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment){
    const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre;
    const { deploy, log, get } = deployments;
    //grabbing from config
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    const governanceToken = await get("GovernanceToken");
    const timeLock = await get("Timelock");
    log("deploying governor>>>>>>>>>>");
    const governorContract = await deploy("GovernorContract", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [
            //governanceToken.address,
            timeLock.address,
            VOTING_DELAY,
            VOTING_PERIOD,
            QUORUM_PERCENTAGE
        ],
        log: true,
    });
}

export default deployGovernorContract;
```

It is throwing the error at lines `const governanceToken = await get("GovernanceToken");` and `const timeLock = await get("Timelock");`. "GovernanceToken", and "Timelock" are the already deployed contracts. The error says...

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/adil/Desktop/MakingDAO/deploy/deployGovernor.ts:
Error: No deployment found for: GovernanceToken
    at get (/home/adil/Desktop/MakingDAO/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:162:17)
```

When I followed the error in `MakingDAO/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:162:17` exactly here, I got this...

```
get: async (name: string) => {
        await this.setup(false);
        const deployment = this.db.deployments[name];
        if (deployment === undefined) {
          throw new Error(`No deployment found for: ${name}`);
        }
        return deployment;
      },
```

Actually it is not getting the deployed contract.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you ran your node bevor running this and deployed your contracts on the correct chain?

so before getting the contract you need to run your node like

```
yarn hardhat node
```

depending on the chain you want to use, you need to fire the command like

```
yarn hardhat run scripts/propose.ts --network localhost
```